# .NET Google Workspace API getting error CS0266

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am generating a user and populating them into our Google Workspace environment but I cannot seem to get the CustomSchemas to work.
I have fiddled around with a few different ways to format it but I still cannot get it to work properly.

```
userGoogleUserWithData = new User()
{
    PrimaryEmail = userEmail,
    Password = generatedPassword,
    Name = new UserName
    {
        GivenName = givenName,
        FamilyName = familyName
    },
    ChangePasswordAtNextLogin = true,
    OrgUnitPath = "/",
    Suspended = false,
    Relations = new List<UserRelation>
    {
        new UserRelation { Type = "manager", Value = googleData.manager } // Set the manager's email
    },
    Addresses = new List<UserAddress>
    {
        new UserAddress
        {
            Type = "work",
            Formatted = googleData.locationAddress,
            Locality = myBranch.branchCity,
            Region = myBranch.branchState,
            PostalCode = myBranch.branchZip,
            Country = myBranch.branchCountry
        }
    },
    Organizations = new List<UserOrganization>
    {
        new UserOrganization
        {
            Title = googleData.jobTitle,
            Primary = true,
            Department = googleData.department,
            CostCenter = googleData.costCenter,
            Description = "user",
            Name = "Test Company"
        }
    },
    CustomSchemas = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["Custom Field Testing"] = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["blah text"] = "Test Value"
        }
    }
};
service.Users.Insert(userGoogleUserWithData).Execute();
```

Custom Field Testing and blah text should be the key values in my workspace. am I getting the formatting wrong?
It continues to give me an Error CS0266 no matter how I set it up.

Full error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 277 Active

Line 277 is:

```
CustomSchemas = new Dictionary<string, object>
```

Comment: _"am I getting the formatting wrong"_ - highly unlikely =) What line exactly in the provided code? And please post full compilation error. Currently this question severely lacks on details.

Comment: Edited the question to include this info, sorry my bad on not including it from the start.

Comment: You seem to have a "simple" type mismatch, should not the line be: `CustomSchemas = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that error is pretty clear - you have type mismatch, you are trying to assign instance of `new Dictionary<string, object>` to `IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>`, so try the followwing:

```
CustomSchemas = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    ["Custom Field Testing"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["blah text"] = "Test Value"
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the complier error! Broke on run time though so I must have a typo with the key names somewhere.